# How to show an facebook like button when offline so that when he click redirected to login page

Tags: android

I have a like button in my html page when online.

but i also want like button to show up when i m offline and when i click on it redirect me to the login page which shows user that he does not have an internet connection

Help me... thanks in advance

Comment: My html page is in my android application

Answer (score 1):

Won't the fact that they're being redirected to a URL tell them that they're offline anyway?